# МПомогите с решением задачи: возведение в степень

Tags: c++, mingw

Задача:mцифра A^B
(Время: 1 сек. Память: 16 Мб Сложность: 21%)
Требуется написать программу, которая находит цифру, на которую оканчивается число A^B. 
Входные данные
Входной файл INPUT.TXT состоит из единственной строки, содержащей два целых числа A и B, разделенных пробелом (1 ≤ A,B ≤ 10000). 
Выходные данные
В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести цифру, на которую оканчивается A в степени B.
Воть мой код, на одном из тестов выдает ошибку

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long a,b,c,k,pw;
    cin>>a>>k;

    c = pow(a%10,k%10);

    cout<<c%10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только на одном? Странно.  `k%10` - ??

Comment: вывод последней цифры путем показа остатка от деления на 10, что не так? Если просят показать последнюю цифру А^В, то зачем прибегать к длинной арифметике

Comment: То есть возведение в квадрат или в двенадцатую степень даст одинаковый результат?

Comment: Спасибо, понял - Исправил, но всё равно неправильный ответ -_-

Comment: Судя по диапазону допустимых значений, происходит переполнение целого. Надо возводить в степень постепенно, отсекая все кроме единиц на каждом шаге.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь accepted

Comment: Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по диапазону допустимых значений, происходит переполнение целого. Надо возводить в степень постепенно, отсекая все кроме единиц на каждом шаге.

---

Эта задачка интереснее, чем выглядит на первый взгляд. Если захотите, мы обсудим оптимизацию решения - использования табличных значений без никакого возведения в степень.